# get rows from mysql db with condition of a column with multi value to search multi value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

first of all, i have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE category_ids IN (24,36,50,60,12);
```

- category_ids column have data like this: 16,24,18

now, i want to search in multi values column with multi value string.
this query have a problem. fetch rows with just id (24). and cant search with 36,50,60,12

in other word, i have two table : 1. category 2. post . so i selected multi category for a post and save the category ids in post table like this (ex: 12,24,16) now i want fetch all post that have category id 24 AND 36 for example

how can i write my query to work? please help!
Thanks

Comment: "_this query have a problem_" What problem does it have? If your `category_ids` are 16, 24 and 18 then obviously 36, 50, 60 and 12 can't be found - because they don't exist.

Comment: Normalize your data and your searching criteria. Or at least one of them (worse).

Answer (score 0):

if your column value is seperated comma

`SELECT * FROM post WHERE category_ids REGEXP ',24|24|24,';`

can't filtering  '24%' or '%24%'

## edit like this

`SELECT * FROM post WHERE category_ids =24 or category_ids REGEXP '^24,|,24$|,24,';`

Comment: Won't this also match 244 or 124 or any string with 24 anywhere?

Comment: i have two table :
1. category
2. post

.
so

i selected multi category for a post and save the category ids in post table like this (ex: 12,24,16)

now i want fetch all post that have id 24.